# PHP GET submission error

Tags: php, html

Ok, I'm trying to program a php page that will allow the user to pick a season and an episode from a form. Then It sends it to a page that plays them all.

Here is the form:

```
<form action="view" method="get">
<select>
 <option name="s" id="s" value="1">1</option>
</select>
<select>
 <option name="e" id="e" value="1">1</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
```

I'll add the other seasons and episodes in later. When they submit the form to the page VIEW, it sends it to the url and adds the question mark, but doesn't define the variables like so

```
http://127.0.0.1/media/show/view/?
```

I've never had this issue before, how do I get it to define the variables using GET in the url? I'm sure I'm missing something simple... Also, I've manually defined the variables in the url and my videos play just fine.

Comment: Because you can't have the `name` on the `option`, only on the `select`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, you can't have a `name` attribute on an option.
You should construct your `select` elements like this:

```
<select name="s">
 <option id="s" value="1">1</option>
</select>
<select name="e">
 <option id="e" value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

That will append them to your url correctly.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Finally hitting the baby OG milestones! ;-)

Comment: Y'er gettin' up there ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'll catch you one day...in 30 years haha

Comment: I had a strategy; I made my first 2,500 in "editing" ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have a strategy, it involves you and me. Basically..... I'm going to rob you!

Comment: ...of all my riches? Good luck, if you like soup... as in "kitchen" lol Gawd, even the church mice have moved out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- We'll be bum-buddies HAHAHAH

Comment: LOL! Around here, that's got a special meaning hahaha (YIPES)